# Modify SOAP header Mustunderstand attribute in WCF client

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-client, soapheader

I am writing a WCF client for a service (not WCF). Getting  an error that Unprocessed 'mustUnderstand' header element: {http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action, because request SOAP contains header with mustunderstand='true'. I have to either set it false or remove the whole header. can you show the way to do that?

Here is the binding code

```
var transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        transportElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;

        var messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        messegeElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11);

        var binding = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, transportElement);
        return binding;
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the header? What binding are you using in your client? The metioned header is from WS-Addressing which can be also turned on in WCF.

Comment: Service did not like the header. Getting this exception System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Unprocessed 'mustUnderstand' header element: {http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action. Added my custom binding code in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this one by setting AddressingVersion to None that did not put the SOAP headers.

here is the code

```
MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11, AddressingVersion.None)
```

Comment: It is many years later and this still seems to be a problem.  However, this fix did not work for me.  Mustunderstand="1" still exists in my security header.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the messageVersion solved my problem. 
`<mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>`